# Exception in controller Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I can't understand where there is an error in my code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Input;
use Redirect;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class PostsController extends Controller
{

   public function getIndex()
   {
     $posts = \App\Models\Post::with('Author')->orderBy('id')->get();
     return view('ind')->with('posts',$posts);
   }

   public function getAdmin()
   {
     return view('addpost');
   }

   public function postAdd()
   {
     \App\Models\Post::create(array(
             'title' => Input::get('title'),
             'content' => Input::get('content'),
             'author_id' => Auth::user()->id
     ));
     return Redirect::route('ind');
   }
}
```

It returns the error:

```
> FatalErrorException in PostsController.php line 20: syntax error,
> unexpected '￼public' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION). In
> line 20 there is the declaration of getadmin() function
```

So I don't understand why it tells me expecting function.

Comment: When I copy and paste your code into my editor there's a weird character on line 18 right after the `getIndex` method. Try commenting out everything after your `getIndex` method or checking for any strange characters and seeing if it runs.

Comment: You definitely forgot to close the scope of a function please paste complete control in one single code block

Comment: @haakym what editor do you use? Because i can't see any weird character on my editor

Comment: @KhanShahrukh now it's in one block but what do you mean with 'you forgot to close the scope of a function'? Where's the mistake?

Comment: Sublime. I only picked up the character when I went to edit your question as the code was in two blocks then I didn't bother editing as I thought the special character was perhaps the issue. It comes out as a question mark in a box.

Comment: Did you try commenting out everything after your getIndex method and seeing if you get an error?

Comment: I cannot rectify any error in your code I looked at it very thoroughly but the code is neat. Try creating this controller again and execute it with every function you declare